# What is the use of the thread parameterless constructor?

Tags: java, multithreading

If the thread constructor has parameters, and the parameter is a function entry, it is equivalent to creating a new thread to execute this function.
However, thread also has a parameterless constructor, and it seems that no member function of the thread class can be bound to an execution function again.

Question: What is the use of the thread object constructed by default? How can the child thread be executed?

Comment: Also, if no answers are satisfactory, please edit your question and explain in more detail what information you need.

Answer (score 5):

When you ask *why* answers are fraught.  It's impossible to see into the mind of the person who designed the language.  I'll take a guess though.

`Thread` also allows subclassing.  For example, this thread class does have an implemented `run()` method, and uses the no-argument (nullity) constructor.

```
public class HelloThread extends Thread {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    System.out.println( "Hello Thread." );
  }
}

new HelloThread().start();
```

So there's more than one way to get a thread object to execute arbitrary code.  The `Runnable` argument isn't always needed.

Comment: Relevant though tangential Q&A: [“implements Runnable” vs “extends Thread” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread-in-java?).